# Insights into WordPress Multi-Site, Domain Mapped, and Multilanguage site using WPML

Tags: multi-language, domain-mapping, plugin-wpml

I have a project with WordPress for a multi-language, multi-country site.

I want to have a structure like:

- domain.com

  - domain.com/es
  - domain.com/de
  - domain.com/fr
- domain.es

  - domain.es/en
- domain.fr

  - domain.fr/en
- domain.de

  - domain.de/en

I was wondering if anyone had any useful articles, tips or insights. The idea is that the .com site be the 'parent' site. The other satellite sites would be in their native language by default, but might have other languages available. Ideally, each individual satellite site could have some leeway to have styles/content that would be different than the parent site.

I also want the parent site to use canonicalization, so that the 'satellite' (country-specific, top-level-domain) sites have priority.

I guess I'm most curious to know about:

Domain mapping and compatibility with WMPL

Thanks